# How to add/remove classes to a button element (on click) based on the number of sets of other elements visible on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've gotten lots of help looking at other people's questions and answers on here over the years but I have finally run into a scenario that's pretty unique from other sites I've built (mostly Wordpress) and could use some help with the Jquery part. I've got everything working the way it should on the front-end BUT the Jquery is ugly and not scalable (as will be obvious when you look at it).

Here's a fiddle showing the working prototype:
https://jsfiddle.net/shellygraham/fnhv53me/

Background: On the front-end the goal is to have a typical loop with four posts visible on page load and the rest hidden, there's a button "Load More Work" below the posts that when clicked shows four more posts and so on and so forth for as many sets of four posts within the loop. Once there aren't anymore posts left to load (final one, two, three or four are displayed) the "Load More Work" button is removed/hidden. It's just like a lot of AJAX "load more" style portfolios, etc. except I can't go that route because my client wants all content loaded immediately for SEO purposes. Therefore I have to hide and show posts instead of loading more posts when the button is clicked.

As previously mentioned, it works fine on the front end but the scalable/lean Jquery part for showing and hiding the button outputted for each set of four is a little over my head.

On a possibly relevant side note: This is a custom Wordpress build and because I'm using Foundation 6 framework grid (specifically, the XY Grid) I can't wrap each set of four posts in a container div without breaking up my layout (each post is six columns) and therefore this is my loop:

```
    <div class="expertise-work">
      <div class="grid-container work-img">
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">

            <?php $counter = 0;
                  $button  = 1;

                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="small-12 xlarge-6 cell work-container not-shown">               
                    <?php post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x work-excerpt">
                        <div class="small-12 large-5 xlarge-4 cell">
                            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 large-7 xlarge-7 xlarge-offset-1 cell">
                            <h2><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php $counter++; ?>

                <?php if( $counter % 4 == 0) { ?>

                    <div class="grid-container button-container not-shown set-<?php echo $button; ?>">
                        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x align-center">
                            <a href="#" class="button show-more-work"><span>Load More Work</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php $button++; ?>

                <?php } ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*I don't have a problem with the loop itself but I posted it for reference. The problem is with my crappy Jquery code.

Anyway, the PHP loop outputs a markup that looks like this (inner content bits abridged for brevity):

```
    <div class="grid-container work-img">
      <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">

        <!-- First set of four (or less) posts -->  
        <div class="small-12 xlarge-6 cell work-container show">                
            stuff
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 xlarge-6 cell work-container show">                
            stuff
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 xlarge-6 cell work-container show">                
            stuff
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 xlarge-6 cell work-container show">                
            stuff
        </div>

        <!-- Button after first set of four posts to load more posts if available -->   
        <div class="grid-container button-container set-1 active">
            <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x align-center">
                <a href="#" class="button show-more-work"><span>Load More Work</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <!-- Second set of four (or less) posts --> 
        <div class="small-12 xlarge-6 cell work-container not-shown">               
            stuff
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 xlarge-6 cell work-container not-shown">               
            stuff
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 xlarge-6 cell work-container not-shown">               
            stuff
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 xlarge-6 cell work-container not-shown">               
            stuff
        </div>

        <!-- Button after second set of four posts to load more posts if available -->  
        <div class="grid-container button-container not-shown set-2">
            <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x align-center">
                <a href="#" class="button show-more-work"><span>Load More Work</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Third set of four (or less) posts - In this case only two posts left so no button afterward -->    
        <div class="small-12 xlarge-6 cell work-container not-shown">               
            stuff
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 xlarge-6 cell work-container not-shown">               
            stuff
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want to stress that there's no way around this markup due to the way the grid works. Solutions have to work around it. Sad but true.

Here's the pertinent css (adapted from scss):

```
.work-container.not-shown { display: none; }
.work-container.show { display: block; }
.button-container.not-shown { display: none; }
.button-container.active { display: inline; }
```

To achieve the "Load More" button behavior of showing on page load after the first four posts (only if there are more than four posts), to display the next set of posts on click and also hide the previous set's button and display the current set's button, until there aren't any more posts to display here is my jquery:

```
// Load More functionality for tax archive page
size_li = $('.work-container').size();
x=4;
if (size_li > 4 ) {
        $('.button-container.set-1').addClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-1').removeClass('not-shown');
    }
$('.work-container:lt('+x+')').addClass('show');
$('.work-container:lt('+x+')').removeClass('not-shown');

$('.button-container.set-1 .show-more-work').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        $('.button-container.set-1').removeClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-1').addClass('not-shown');

        $('.button-container.set-2').addClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-2').removeClass('not-shown');

    x= (x+4 <= size_li) ? x+4 : size_li;
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').addClass('show');
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').removeClass('not-shown');
});

$('.button-container.set-2 .show-more-work').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        $('.button-container.set-2').removeClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-2').addClass('not-shown');

        $('.button-container.set-3').addClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-3').removeClass('not-shown');

    x= (x+4 <= size_li) ? x+4 : size_li;
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').addClass('show');
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').removeClass('not-shown');
});

$('.button-container.set-3 .show-more-work').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        $('.button-container.set-3').removeClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-3').addClass('not-shown');

        $('.button-container.set-4').addClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-4').removeClass('not-shown');

    x= (x+4 <= size_li) ? x+4 : size_li;
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').addClass('show');
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').removeClass('not-shown');
});


$('.button-container.set-4 .show-more-work').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        $('.button-container.set-4').removeClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-4').addClass('not-shown');

        $('.button-container.set-5').addClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-5').removeClass('not-shown');

    x= (x+4 <= size_li) ? x+4 : size_li;
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').addClass('show');
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').removeClass('not-shown');
});

$('.button-container.set-5 .show-more-work').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        $('.button-container.set-5').removeClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-5').addClass('not-shown');

        $('.button-container.set-6').addClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-6').removeClass('not-shown');

    x= (x+4 <= size_li) ? x+4 : size_li;
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').addClass('show');
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').removeClass('not-shown');
});

$('.button-container.set-6 .show-more-work').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        $('.button-container.set-6').removeClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-6').addClass('not-shown');

        $('.button-container.set-7').addClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-7').removeClass('not-shown');

    x= (x+4 <= size_li) ? x+4 : size_li;
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').addClass('show');
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').removeClass('not-shown');
});

$('.button-container.set-7 .show-more-work').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        $('.button-container.set-7').removeClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-7').addClass('not-shown');

        $('.button-container.set-8').addClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-8').removeClass('not-shown');

    x= (x+4 <= size_li) ? x+4 : size_li;
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').addClass('show');
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').removeClass('not-shown');
});
```

I'm sure it's pretty obvious where my shortcomings with Jquery are - I can't figure out how to make the button click for each set add and remove classes without reiterating the same code for each ".button-container.set-[number]". I have a hunch there's some way to do it more elegantly using the modulus operator but I'm a total novice with that. I know there's a better way to do this but I've had no luck finding it on here or via Google.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Please let me know if you need more information or something I said doesn't make sense. Just looking at the fiddle probably makes more sense than how I've explained the situation.

Comment: A couple things. 1) Most people aren't going to help you with this. It's a mountain of text to read. I suggest paring it down as much as possible while still articulating your issue. 2) Your fiddle doesn't work. 3) If I've understood your mountain of text correctly :-), I think you need to take a look at jQuery's like selector `$("[class^=main]")` http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @JamesHill Thanks for the feedback. I know it's a lot but I see answers that misinterpret the question all the time on here so I was trying to be thorough. Can you re-try the fiddle? I just re-ran it and it works the way it should.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a data attribute to your .button-container that will instruct the javascript on what it's activating.

replace:

`<div class="grid-container button-container set-1 active">`

with: 

`<div class="grid-container button-container set-1 active" activate=".set-1">`

new javascript:

```
size_li = $('.work-container').size();
x=4;
if (size_li > 4 ) {
        $('.button-container.set-1').addClass('active');
        $('.button-container.set-1').removeClass('not-shown');
    }
$('.work-container:lt('+x+')').addClass('show');
$('.work-container:lt('+x+')').removeClass('not-shown');

$('.show-more-work').each(function(i, $tag) {
  $tag.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // deactivate, hide everything
      $('.button-container').removeClass('active').addClass('not-shown');

    // activate current class
      $($tag.data('activate')).addClass('active').removeClass('not-shown');

    x= (x+4 <= size_li) ? x+4 : size_li;
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').addClass('show');
    $('.work-container:lt('+x+')').removeClass('not-shown');
  })
})
```

$tag.click(... might need to be $($tag).click(...

I'd suggest trying to consolidate .active and .not-shown into a single class so you don't have to juggle so much around.